# Append to a table when tbody is absent and how to make all existing jqueries work for that row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery to append to a table dynamically based on user interaction and data received from the server. Now each column in the table has some specific class and some style attributes like the column itemId is hidden and so on. My dynamic addition is working fine if I already have one row but if its none it just adds another header row which I can understand is because my code copies the last tr element. Question is how do I go about adding a row to 'tbody' when their are no rows.

```
    function responseTopicAdded(data) {
        $('#dialog-modal').dialog('close');
        rowcopy = $('#datatable tr:last').clone();
        rowcopy.children().each(function() {
            switch($(this).attr('class')) {
                case 'Name':
                    $(this).html(data.Name);
                    break;
                case 'Description':
                    $(this).html(data.Description);
                    break;
                case 'Icon':
                    $(this).html('<img src='+ data.Icon +'/>');
                    break;
                case 'itemId':
                    $(this).html(data.itemId);
            }
        });
        $('#datatable tr:last').after($(rowcopy));
    }
```

My second question is that my table cells respond to a double click. But the newly added row never responds (even when there are previous rows and the row is added normally).

Why doesn't the listener work on the new row?

My listener goes like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    try {
        $("td").dblclick(function() {
            // ... my code goes here
    }catch(a){
        alert(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use template approach instead of cloning the last tr.

Comment: Could you please ellaborate?

Comment: Ok. first of all your statement `Question is how do I go about adding a column to 'tbody' when their are no rows.` you meant row instead of colunm right?

Comment: Yeah that. I made the edit.

Comment: Ok i will prepare a sample for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with template approach to create a template for your table row to be cloned when required.

Say your table is this:

```
<table id="datatable">
    <thead>
          <tr><th>Name</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>icon</th>
          <th>itemID</th></tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

When you populate:

```
//Create the template here// or keep it in HTML itself in a hidden div or something.
var template = $("<tr><td class='Name'></td><td class='Description'></td><td class='Icon'></td><td class='itemId'></td></tr>");

$(function () {

var newRow = $(template).clone(); //Clone the template

//just an initial load
newRow.find('.Name').text('AAA');
newRow.find('.Description').text('Some Description');
newRow.find('.Icon').text('Some Icon');
newRow.find('.itemId').text('1234');

//Initially clone
$('#datatable').find('tbody').append(newRow);

    //register the handler using event delegation
    $('#datatable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        alert('clicked on ' + $(this).find('.Name').text());
    });

    $('#addNew').on('click', function () {
        var rowcopy = $(template).clone(); //Clone the template
        var data = {
            Name: 'BBB',
            Description: 'Some Description',
            Icon: 'http://placehold.it/32x32',
            itemId: '45676'
        };

       //Set the Css class name based on even odd row
       rowcopy.addClass(function(){
        return $('#datatable tbody tr').length % 2 == 0 ? "odd" : "even";
       });

        rowcopy.children().each(function () {
            switch ($(this).attr('class')) {
                case 'Name':
                    $(this).html(data.Name);
                    break;
                case 'Description':
                    $(this).html(data.Description);
                    break;
                case 'Icon':
                    $(this).html('<img src=' + data.Icon + '/>');
                    break;
                case 'itemId':
                    $(this).html(data.itemId);
            }
        });
        $('#datatable tbody').append($(rowcopy)); //Append it to the tbody.
    });

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nDwV2/)**

For adding even/odd styles you can use css itself.

```
#datatable tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#cecece;
}
#datatable tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

If not you want to do it with the class then:

```
rowcopy.addClass(function(){
            return $('#datatable tbody tr').length % 2 == 0 ? "odd" : "even";
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/349z7/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a much better and elegant solution.
Just one more thing my tr element is like if its an even row it has a class even else class is odd (that is for css basically)

Comment: ok. you dont need to add a class at all if you want i can write just with css for you.

Comment: @SilentPro Check this you can just do with css. http://jsbin.com/orimeh/4/edit If you insist on adding class let me know we can just add it.

Comment: @SilentPro Use append instead of after, see my update and demo code.

Comment: I know I can do that but the table is generated by django-tables2 I dont write my own css. SO I guess I do need the class?

Comment: @SilentPro given both the options in the answer now, you can choose what you need. :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason the double click event doesn't work on newly added rows is because you are binding the click event before the elements exist. Try binding with this style (event delegation is the term):

```
$("#datatable").on("dblclick", "td", function() { //do stuff });
```

As per adding a `tbody` when one is not present, simply do a check to see if one exists:

```
if ($("#datatable tbody").length) { //it exists! } else { //it doesnt exist! }
```

Comment: Can you please explain why one would work over the other.
I have not tried this but maybe it would work as it usually does with expert help at stackoverflow but I'd feel better if I got some reason for why its happening.

Comment: @SilentPro -- As I say in the answer, your current selector waits (presumably inside a DOM ready statement) waits until the page is ready, then binds to your `td` elements, that's fine. Now you're adding new `td` elements, but since these weren't here at DOM ready, they have no idea they should have a click event assigned to them. That's where event delegation comes in, this new selector is basically saying, click anywhere on the `#datatable` and I'll if it happens to be a `td`, ill fire!

Comment: So I should take this out of the $(document).ready(function(){}); block??

Comment: @SilentPro -- Keep it in there, we're still binding this handler to the `#datatable` element, so the page still has to wait until that element has rendered.

Comment: Thanks.
Regarding the other thing I think I really have to write the whole classes and styles.